# How to change background color of a container using a separate button?

Tags: react-native, button, onclick, background-color, react-props

There is a button at the bottom that when I click I want it to change the background color of the pink containers. How do I make it work, linking the button to the container?

```
import ListCar from './ListCar';
import {useState} from 'react';

export default function App() {

  const [color, setColor] = useState(true);
  const toggle=()=>{
    setColor(!color);
  }
  return

 
    <StatusBar style="light"/>
    <View style={{ maxheight:10,  backgroundColor: "lightgrey" }}>
        <Button onPress={toggle} classname={'container'} title="Change Background"></Button>
    </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

```
export default ListCar = (props) => {

return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View>
          <Image source={require("./bmw.jpg")} style={{width:150, height:150, resizeMode:'contain'}}/>
    )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    container:{
        backgroundColor: 'pink',
        marginTop: 20,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        padding:5,
        
      },
```

Comment: are they in the same screen or component? Looking at what you wrote you might need to consider using `Context`

Comment: Where do you use <ListCar /> component??